# How to give a blue style to a NSButton without having to set a keyEquivalent for it?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsbutton

I am using this code below for my NSButton, for having the blue style Button. But this code make my Button react to return key on keyboard, which it is not my wish, my goal is having this style without having to set a keyEquivalent for my Button, how can I customize my NSButton for this goal?

```
let myButton: NSButton = NSButton()
myButton.bezelStyle = .rounded
myButton.keyEquivalent = "\r"
```

Comment: You can of course do as you wish but don't you think this might be confusing to the user when your app doesn't follow the MacOS standard behaviour?

Comment: You mean any blue style NSButton must or should have keyEquivalent? Actually I did not think that way thanks for info, but how to have blue style button without setting the keyEquivalent?

Comment: That is not a style, the button is highlighted to indicate the keyEquivalent behavior (the return key).

Comment: @red_menace:  I am not talking about highlight, highlight thing is another thing, highlight comes when we start pressing on button, in my question I never talked about pressing on button, if you run my code the button has a blue style from begging and that is what I want, the thing that I do not want is defining a keyEquivalent.

Comment: What I am saying is that is not a "style" - the API highlights a button with a return key equivalent to indicate its behavior (this is different from the various alternate title/image or bezel changes to indicate a button press).  If a button you create happens to be the current key view, it will also have a border highlight.  You might take a look at using an image or layer.

Comment: @red_menace: I not trying to make a custom button, that would be not my goal here. I am just trying to customize the NSButton the way I need. If wanted to make a custom button I would not need to ask this question.

Comment: Did you try adding an image which is nothing but a rounded rect with the color you want?

Comment: I do not want make a custom Button, I want use the apple api for this goal.

Comment: You are using a standard NSButton.  All you would be doing is adding an image to it; that doesn't make it 'custom'.  If you look at the documentation there is no method for setting the background of an NSButton; Apple doesn't support it.

Comment: Why you do not get the point of question? when I use `.rounded` for `myButton.bezelStyle` I just using api, yes I could go to layer of button and round it by myself but that would be a custom button not the customized button. Are you here to help for solving the issue or trying tell me what is the meaning of custom? I got no time for that, no thanks

Comment: Sorry, 'custom' implies a subclass of NSButton which you would not be doing by adding an image to a standard NSButton.  To my knowledge there is no other way to get what you are asking for with possible exception of layer.

Comment: Thanks for information, I can make a custom NSButton as you said from the Super class no issue there, but most of the time the things we want build as a custom one they already exist in super one, and just need some adjustment. That is why I wanted be sure before putting my time for building a sub class of NSButton.

Answer (score 0):

The following source code will create a blue NSButton using an inline image which is a blue colored rounded rect near the same size as the button. The button title color was changed to white to make it more visible.

```
// **** Inline Image **** //
let fillColor = NSColor(calibratedRed: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
let image = NSImage.init(size: NSMakeSize(128.0, 22.0))
let imgRect = NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, 128.0, 22.0)
image.lockFocus()
let roundedRect = NSBezierPath (roundedRect:imgRect, xRadius:4, yRadius:4)
fillColor.set()
roundedRect.fill()
image.unlockFocus()

// **** Button **** //
let myBtn = NSButton (frame:NSMakeRect( 150, 100, 140, 24 ))
myBtn.bezelStyle = .rounded
myBtn.image = image
let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12), .foregroundColor: NSColor.white]
myBtn.attributedTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Show Window", attributes:attributes)
window.contentView!.addSubview (myBtn)
```